# Как задать длинну результирующего аудио фала в библиотеке ffmpeg?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Есть `mp3` и `aac` файлы. Первый продолжительностью 60 секунд, второй 30. Для их объединения использую `ffmpeg` и в ней команду:

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -i .\sound.mp3 -i .\dict.aac -filter_complex "[
0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[aout]" -map "[aout]" .\output.mp3
```

Команду для объединения брал отсюда: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation (2 × stereo → stereo)

Получается файл продолжительностью 30 секунд, а нужно сделать 60(То есть продолжительность второго файла или большего). Подскажите, как доработать команду, что бы получить файл необходимой длинны? Использоваться библиотека будет в `Android` проекте используя модуль https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Comment: Эм.. exe в андроиде - это как-то подозрительно... Или нет?

Comment: Библиотека https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java будет подключатся. В Windows через консоль проверяю пока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Именно с задачей продолжительности, помогла команда:

> .\ffmpeg.exe -y -i dictionaryFilePath -i songFilePath -filter_complex [0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest -c:a libmp3lame resultFilePath

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать обертку ffmpeg, например ( https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java ), а затем использовать подход командной строки ffmpeg.

Преимущество оболочки заключается в том, что она должна скрывать большую часть сложности интеграции ffmpeg, а также позволяет использовать синтаксис командной строки и использовать все общие обсуждения и поддержку ffmpeg для этого.

Затем вы можете использовать обычный синтаксис ffmpeg trim:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -vf trim = 60: 120
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, что делает эта команда

Comment: Это просто синтаксис .Посмтари ссылку что я дал она поможет

Comment: В ссылке указана библиотека, которую я и собираюсь использовать. Вопрос именно в том, как мне доработать команду из вопроса, что бы я получал необходимый файл.